# No field `storeId` on type `&mut std::option::Option<BusinessInfo<T>>`

Tags: substrate-node-template

I need to add an item in storage but when I build the project, I get this error:

> error[E0609]: no field `storeId` on type `&mut std::option::Option<BusinessInfo<T>>`
> --> pallets/bussines/src/lib.rs:171:25
> |
> 171 |                 ensure!((Some(store.storeId) == Some(store_id)), <Error>::StoreItemNotFound);

I don't know what the problem is.

this is `BusinessInfo` struct:

```
#[derive(Clone, Encode, Decode, PartialEq, RuntimeDebug, TypeInfo)]
#[scale_info(skip_type_params(T))]
#[codec(mel_bound())]
pub struct BusinessInfo<T: Config> {
    logo: Vec<u8>,
    storeId: [u8; 16],
    owner: <T as frame_system::Config>::AccountId,
    description: Vec<u8>,
    name: Vec<u8>,
}
```

I tried to check if business exists add item if not show error:

```
    #[pallet::weight(10000)]
    #[transactional]
    pub fn add_item(
        origin: OriginFor<T>,
        store_id: [u8; 16],
        media: Vec<u8>,
        title: Vec<u8>,
        description: Vec<u8>,
        price: u32,
        count: u32,
    ) -> DispatchResult {
        let who = ensure_signed(origin)?;

        let item_id = Self::gen_dna();

        let item_info = BusinessItem {
            media: media.clone(),
            title: title.clone(),
            description: description.clone(),
            price: price.clone(),
            count: count.clone(),
            itemId: item_id,
        };

        Business::<T>::mutate(who.clone(), |store| -> DispatchResult {
            ensure!((Some(store.storeId) == Some(store_id)), <Error<T>>::StoreItemNotFound);
            let mut store_item_vec: Vec<BusinessItem> = Vec::new();
            store_item_vec.push(item_info);
            <Items<T>>::insert(item_id, who.clone(), store_item_vec);
            Ok(())
        });

        Self::deposit_event(Event::ItemCreated(Some(item_id)));

        Ok(())
    }
```

and this is `Business Storage`:

```
    #[pallet::storage]
#[pallet::getter(fn business)]
pub(super) type Business<T: Config> =
    StorageMap<_, Twox64Concat, T::AccountId, BusinessInfo<T>>;
```

Answer (score 3):

Each storage item has a `QueryKind` set at declaration. This `QueryKind` defines the behavior/return value of functions like `get` and also `mutate`. There are currently three different query kinds defined in Substrate:

- [`ValueQuery`](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/0ee03277c33b6334ddba7434e014fa637dcb6107/frame/support/src/storage/types/mod.rs#L115): Returns `Default::default()` if the value doesn't exist in the state or the value from the state.
- [`OptionQuery`](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/0ee03277c33b6334ddba7434e014fa637dcb6107/frame/support/src/storage/types/mod.rs#L71) Returns `None` if the value doesn't exist in the state or the value from the state wrapped in `Some(_)`.
- [`ResultQuery`](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/0ee03277c33b6334ddba7434e014fa637dcb6107/frame/support/src/storage/types/mod.rs#L91) Returns `Err(_)` if the value doesn't exist in the state or the value from the state wrapped in `Ok(_)`.

The default `QueryKind` is `OptionQuery`. In your example this would mean that your closure that you pass to `mutate` gets passed a `&mut Option<BusinessInfo<T>>`. So, writing:

```
Business::<T>::mutate(who.clone(), |store| -> DispatchResult {
    if let Some(store) = &mut store {
        let mut store_item_vec: Vec<BusinessItem> = Vec::new();
        store_item_vec.push(item_info);
        <Items<T>>::insert(item_id, who.clone(), store_item_vec);
        Ok(())
    } else {
        Err(<Error<T>>::StoreItemNotFound.into())
    }
});
```

Will fix your compile error.

[Here](https://docs.substrate.io/build/runtime-storage/#declaring-storage-items) you see some examples on how to declare the query kind.